# Hardhat - We couldn't initialize the sample project because this file already exists

Tags: hardhat

i am having this error in hardhat v2.11.2 version. I get this warning after npx hardhat -> create a javascript project " We couldn't initialize the sample project because this file already exists: README.md" "Please delete or move them and try again." I'm new to these things and I don't know how to solve it please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this command on terminal : "rm README.md"

And try "npx hardhat" again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).